# Why there's a gap between the right of the picture and the page's right edge when I used "scope fading=south"? How can I remove it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, includegraphics, tikz-node

The MWE is

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [anchor=north,scope fading=south,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [anchor=north,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When I use `scope fading=south` in the node command, there will be a very thin gap at the right side of the image although I used the option `inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt`, just like the screenshot below

[image: Figure 1. There's a very thin gap at the right side of the "example-image-a" when use "scope fading=south"]

However, if I deleted the option `scope fading=south`, the gap will disappear, just like the screenshot below

[image: Figure 2. There's no gap at the right side of the picture]

So, how can I remove the gap?

Comment: Either I don't understand the issue or I can't reproduce it using your code. I added `\pagecolor{red}` to the preamble to try to make any gap more obvious, but nothing doing. There's no line of red showing the gap.

Comment: @cfr I've edited the question and make the page color red to make the gap more visible. I means that I want to insert a picture that with the width of `\paperwidth` at the top of the page (to fill the paper horizontally), however there will be a gap between the picture and the edge of the page when I make the picture transparent gradually.

Comment: @cfr You can open this overleaf link https://www.overleaf.com/project/657487aa9a1924c0ca51088d to compile the MWE, and you will find that there will be a gap between the right side of the image and the edge of the page; and a gap between the top side of the image and the edge of the page.

Comment: I get a permissions error.

Comment: Check by downloading/viewing the PDF rather than Overleaf's rendering.

Comment: It is probably just a visual artefact, but there may also be slight discrepancies because the included image's scaling will introduce some level of inaccuracy just because TeX's calculations aren't accurate. But the inaccuracies don't usually result in visible discrepancies unless they're cumulative.

Comment: Testing with local MiKTeX installation (recent version), I can't reproduce your problem. Both nodes has equal size and are equal positioned on the page.

Comment: I can reproduce this with an up-to-date texlive2023 https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdFAQ.png (but I don't know the solution)

Comment: Same happens if one replaces the image with a rectangular path

Comment: Does the issue persist if you compile with an earlier TeX Live? Overleaf lets you pick the edition of TL, so try one of the earlier versions. I'm using TL 2023, but not completely up-to-date. (But Overleaf's probably is even less up-to-date.)

Comment: If I really zoom in, I can maybe see something, but nothing like the margin in @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's image. (Maybe I didn't zoom enough?) I assumed that was just my viewer - things don't always appear accurately e.g. line widths don't look quite right etc. I'm not sure how to tell if I'm seeing something or not.

Comment: @cfr The screenshot from my comment is with a zoom of 500%. I can reproduce this back until TL19 (that's the oldest I've installed on this machine)

Comment: What happens if you don't use `overlay` and set the page margins to zero? I don't know how to tell if the issue is still there or not.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Given the scaling won't be perfectly accurate, is the result clearly wrong? That's what I'd think at the top, anyway. I don't understand why it wouldn't be centred, but presumably there are calculations there, too?

Comment: @cfr A limited accuracy is certainly expected, but what is puzzling for me is that the fading behaves differently than a normal node/path/whatever.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Far more calculations are done in the case of a fading, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\node[preaction={draw, red}, draw, green, scope fading=south] (n) {\includegraphics[width=80cm]{example-image-a.jpg}};
\draw[blue] ([yshift=1pt]n.north west) -- +(80,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Letter A faded at bottom]

Upper right corner:

[image: Green and red shifted frames]

First a `fading` from the picture with the correct size(red) is made. This `fading` is much smaller than the picture. (see by using the `fit fading=false` option). `fading transform` options are applied and the fading is fitted to fill the area. This fitting/stretching presumably has rounding errors. The error is more pronounced for larger fadings, but not systematically. Finally the node boundary(green) is created.

As I see it, there is no good way to avoid this rounding error other than manual adjustments

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack you can increase the width of your image a tiny bit:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [anchor=north,scope fading=south,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\paperwidth+1pt]{example-image-a.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [anchor=north,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm...The problem can be "solved" by increase the width of the image, but this cannot fundamentally solve the problem - after all, I don’t know why this gap occurs.